# How to get list of all past calls in freeswitch?

Tags: freeswitch

I can get list of current calls from fs_cli using

```
show calls
```

But how can I get list of past calls that already was finished?

Answer (score 0):

Calls are recorder using Call Detail Record (CDR) for FS see this https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/CDR